# Viewing the call stack

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I just can't get the call stack to show up in VB.NET Visual Studio 2015.
In C++ I can easily do that, but for some reason, in VB.NET I can't get it to show up.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whilst your application is running** you need to click on `Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack` located on the main toolstrip, or you can use the default `Ctrl + L` shortcut

Comment: Isn't it possible the activate it all the time so that I don't have to start it up each time I run my app? Also, my call stack is always empty. What could be the reason? Thank you.

Comment: Once you open the call stack, it will reopen each time you run your application, you dont need to do it manually each time

Comment: @tmighty : I believe the call stack is only shown once you stop execution. Have you tried placing a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I was wishing that I could see more of the stack count. I'm only getting the last 2 calls.